# Convert VARCHAR2 to UTF-8 in Oracle 12

Tags: oracle-12c, character-set, unicode

I need to convert VARCHAR2 columns that store text in **unkown** character sets into a standard UTF-8 BLOB.

The table has more columns, but the ones of interest to me are:

```
ADDRESS     POST
----------  --------------
gibberish1  gibberish2
gibberish3  gibberish4
```

The "gibberish" is actually good content. It's just I can't determine the specific character set. I assume the engine knows it internally.

If an ideal UTF8() function existed my query could concatenate the whole thing doing:

```
SELECT RAWTOHEX(UTF8(ADDRESS)) || ',' || RAWTOHEX(UTF8(POST)) FROM TAB1;
```

Is there any function that can convert to UTF8 without knowing the existing encoding?

Comment: So, not quite sure what those two columns could contain...  Greek character set, Japanese? And you want to end up with a `B`inary `L`arge `Ob`ject?  Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the current character set? Is DB expected to support other languages?

Comment: My bad, I meant UTF-8 instead of Unicode.

Comment: "I assume the engine knows it internally" -- your assumption is wrong. The data might appear as "gibberish" to you if you incorrectly configure your client NLS settings.

Comment: @mustaccio Ah... so the Oracle engine does not store the character set, but it's something the client must provide at runtime?

Comment: UTF8 supports emojis. You should be able to test with that. If you still get gibberish, it's your client.